# Dynamic Data of amChart in AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, http, amcharts

I am trying to make a chart using `amChart` in `AngularJS Directive`. It works on hardcoded data but when I tried to change the way it get to display the data from a json file, it doesn't work at all. But when I `console.log` the data I am trying to get I received a `json data` I expected but again the chart is not rendering/displaying the data.

**CHARTS.DIRECTIVE.JS**

```
(function(){
"use strict";

var myApp = angular.module('testchart', []);

myApp.directive('test', ['$http',
function($http){
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div id="testchart" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            var chart = false;
            var data = [];



            function generateChartData() {


                $http.get('http://localhost:81/......./testdata.json')
                    .then(function(req, res) {
                    var data = req.data;
                    //return data;
                    console.log(data); 
                });
            }    

            generateChartData();

            var initChart = function() {
              if (chart) chart.destroy();
              var config = scope.config || {};
               chart = AmCharts.makeChart("testchart", {
            "type": "serial",
            "theme": "none",
            "marginLeft": 20,
            "pathToImages": "vendor/amchart/images",
            "dataProvider": data,
            "valueAxes": [{
                "axisAlpha": 0,
                "inside": true,
                "position": "left",
                "ignoreAxisWidth": true
            }],
            "graphs": [{
                "balloonText": "[[category]]<br><b><span style='font-size:14px;'>[[value]]</span></b>",
                "bullet": "round",
                "bulletSize": 6,
                "lineColor": "#d1655d",
                "lineThickness": 2,
                "negativeLineColor": "#637bb6",
                "type": "smoothedLine",
                "valueField": "value"
            }],
            "chartScrollbar": {},
            "chartCursor": {
                "categoryBalloonDateFormat": "YYYY",
                "cursorAlpha": 0,
                "cursorPosition": "mouse"
            },
            "dataDateFormat": "YYYY",
            "categoryField": "year",
            "categoryAxis": {
                "minPeriod": "YYYY",
                "parseDates": true,
                "minorGridAlpha": 0.1,
                "minorGridEnabled": true
            }
        });

        initChart();

            };


       }   

    }
}]);

})();
```

Again if the data is hardcoded in the chart it works perfectly.
`console.log` returns expected json data.

I don't know what to do anymore, I've been a days trying to solve this problem.

**Edit/Update(2):**

I got it work but in other way though, but it does what I wanted to do. But I don't know if it is a right way to do it.

Updated [Plnkr link to my work](https://plnkr.co/edit/3jgURMlMHcQwuSdZ51wS?p=preview)

Comment: You could initiate the chart and pass the data after using `chart.validateNow(data, false);`. [See the documentation for validateNow](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#validateNow).

Comment: I still can't make it work. Thanks anyway. See my Plnkr link, maybe you know how to make it work.